# How to follow DRY principles in different namespaces Rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4, namespaces

Basically I've developed an app which has two namespaces: `admin`, `api` and the public one (simply `resources :users` for instance). All works fine, however I'm repeating myself quite a bit as some of the controllers in `api` for instance could easily be used in `admin`.

How can I DRY my code in this case keeping the namespaces?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways I can think of doing it:

1. **(NOT RECOMMENDED)** - Send the urls to the same controller in your routes.rb file.
2. **Shared namespace that your controllers inherit from**

For example you could have:

```
# controllers/shared/users_controller.rb
class Shared::UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
end


# controllers/api/users_controller.rb
class Api::UsersController < Shared::UsersController
end


# controllers/admin/users_controller.rb
class Admin::UsersController < Shared::UsersController
end
```

The above would allow you to share your index action across the relevant controllers. Your routes file in this case would look like this:

```
# config/routes.rb
namespace :api do
  resources :users
end
namespace :admin do
  resources :users
end
```

That's definitely a lot of code to share one action, but the value multiplies as the number of shared actions does, and, most importantly, your code is located in one spot.

Comment: Would it make a difference to have the shared controllers in the main controller directory? In `app/controllers`?

Comment: no, either way is fine, it just depends on how you want to organize it. I do think that having the shared controllers in a shared folder provides more clarity though

Comment: That didn't work though. The API controller (for instance) was inheriting from `ApplicationController` while the shared controller doesn't. When I added `class Shared::PostsController < ActionController::Base` it didn't work and I started to get loads of errors

Comment: sorry, any of the base controllers should inherit from ApplicationController. I'm updating the answer now