# How to use respond_to for json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a bit confused: I'm writing a centralised controller as per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694495/how-to-follow-dry-principles-in-different-namespaces-rails-4-2/30697070?noredirect=1#comment49538986_30697070) and am getting a bit confused on the `respond_to` method works.

In a `API::Controller` I'd have something like this:

```
def index
  @post = Post.all
  render json: @posts
end
```

And on the js (AngularJS) side of things I'd have something like this:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Token token='+ $scope.user.auth_token;

$http.get('/api/posts').success(function (data) {

  $scope.posts = data;

});
```

That works fine on the API controller, however I want to use a shared controller:

```
def index
  @post = Post.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render layout: 'admin' }
    format.json { render json: @invoices }
  end
end
```

But when I try to do the an ajax call it seems the API is responding with `html` rather than `json`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append `.json` at the end of the URL you are trying to hit with. This way, server will know that request is demanding data in JSON format, while the default format is HTML.

If you are using jQuery to do AJAX, and want to receive data back in JSON format without appending `.json` at the end, you can use then use the function [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), or can pass simply the option `dataType: "json"` in [`$.jquery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function call:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json", // To receive data back in JSON
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: success
});
```

Comment: I'll accept the reply shortly (it seems I need to wait 5 mins). A question though, is there a way I can accept json without the `.json` at the end of the url? This doesn't seem to be a requirement in most APIs

Comment: I'm using AngularJS. I'm also using a Chrome extension called Postman to test the API and it only works if I add `.json` to it. I guess I need to set `json` in the header. Thanks

Comment: I've updated my question. Regarding you said, "This doesn't seem to be a requirement in most APIs". Well, most APIs respond with JSON per se. And in case, if they provide multiple responses, then it is your responsibility to send the correct parameter to get back data in JSON.